# Why it will terminate even if I used signl(SIGINT, sig_int)?

Tags: linux, signals, interrupt

As you see, This is a sample in APUE.

```
#include "apue.h"

static void sig_int(int sig);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[MAXLINE];
    pid_t pid;
    int status;

    if (signal(SIGINT, sig_int) == SIG_ERR) //sig_int is a simple handler function
        err_sys("signal error");

    printf("%% ");
    while (fgets(buf, MAXLINE, stdin) != NULL) {
    //This is a loop to implement a simple shell
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the signal handler

```
void sig_int(int sig)   
/*When I enter Ctrl+C, It'll say a got SIGSTOP, but it would terminate.*/
{
    if (sig == SIGINT)
        printf("got SIGSTOP\n");
}
```

When I enter Ctrl+C, It'll say got SIGSTOP, but it terminates right now.

Comment: I think it shouldn't teminate when I Enter Ctrl+C, but it do :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short version is that the signal interrupts the current system call. You're doing `fgets()`, which likely now blocks in a `read()` system-call. The `read()` call is interrupted, it returns -1 and sets `errno` to `EINTR`.

This causes `fgets` to return NULL, your loop ends, and the program is finished.

## Some background

glibc on linux implements two different concepts for `signal()`. One where system calls are automatically restarted across signals, and one where they are not.

When a signal occurs and the process is blocked in a system call, the system call is interrupted("cancelled"). Execution resumes in the user space application, and the signal handler occurs. The interrupted system call will return an error, and set errno to `EINTR`.

What happens next depends on whether system calls are restarted or not across signals.

If system calls are restartable, the runtime (glibc) simply retries the system call. For the `read()` system call, this would be similar to `read()` being implemented as:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)
{
  ssize_t sz;
  while ((sz = syscall_read(fd, buf, len)) == -1 
          && errno == EINTR);
  return sz;
```

}

If system calls are not automatically restarted, `read()` would behave  similar to:

```
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t len)
{
  ssize_t sz;
  sz = syscall_read(fd, buf, len));
  return sz;
}
```

In the latter case it would be up to your application to check whether read() failed because it was interrupted by a signal. And it is up you, to determine if `read()` just failed temporarily due to a signal getting handled, and it's up you you to re-try the `read()` call

## signal vs sigaction

By using `sigaction()` instead of `signal()`, you get control over
whether system calls are restared or not. The relevant flag you specify with `sigaction()` is

> SA_RESTART
>                     Provide behavior compatible with BSD signal semantics by making certain system calls restartable across signals. 
>   This flag is meaningful only when establishing a sig‐
>                     nal handler.  See signal(7) for a discussion of system call restarting.

## BSD vs SVR4 semantics

If you use `signal()`, it depends on what semantics you want. As seen in the description of `SA_RESTART`, if it is BSD signal semantics, system calls are restarted. This is the default behavior in glibc.

Another difference is that BSD semantics leave the signal handler installed by `signal()` installed after a signal is handled. SVR4 semantics uninstalls the signal handler, and your signal handler will have to re-install the handler if you want to catch more signals.

## apue.h

The "apue.h" however, defines the macro `_XOPEN_SOURCE 600` before including `<signal.h>`. This will cause signal() to have SVR4 semantics, where system calls are *not* restarted. Which will cause your fgets() call to "fail".

## Don't use signal(), use sigaction()

Due to all these differences in behavior, use sigaction() instead of signal. sigaction() lets you control what happens instead of having the semantics change based on a (possibly) hidden `#define` as is the case with `signal()`

Comment: Excellent answer. IMHO you could also add: don't call printf() from inside a signal handler.

Comment: I'd also add that it's better to make the condition of the loop `feof(stdin)` and handle other failures inside the loop and only quit if impossible to handle.

Comment: @nos, right. That was not intended to be copy-pasted but thought upon. In fact, the condition of the loop can't be `feof(stdin)` (it should have _at least_ had a `!`). What I meant was to terminate the loop by looking at `feof(stdin)` instead of the return value of `fgets`. Sorry if that caused confusion.

Comment: You would anyway need to check the return value of fgets(). There are conditions where feof() will not be true, but fgets() still failed for an unrecoverable reason - checking feof() will add no value.